# Why does IE not display position:absolute like it's supposed to?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Internet Explorer 9 is not properly displaying an absolutely positioned element. The parent is relative, so the absolute element should be "absolute" relative to the parent div. However, it is acting much closer to "fixed" behavior. When I try to trigger hasLayout on the involved elements, it shows everything inline.

The element in question is the .programs-list div that appears when you click on a region and then a country.

This happens in all versions of IE.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Which parent is relative? I don't see it. When I define some height for the parent div and make its position relative, the `.programs-list` div moves inside it.

Answer (score 0):

After analyzing your HTML structure, you need to set your `div#main-wrapper` with a `position:relative` in order to keep the popup over the map area.

**CSS**

```
#main-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
```